# Conic fitting with pseudoinverse technique

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

I am trying to fit points of an ellipse to my model using pseudoinverse technique described in [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/ZhangIVC-97-01.pdf) paper (it's in section 4.1). I'm sure that my understanding is wrong, please, could you give me guidelines what I am doing wrong?

My test image is [this](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/4592/ellipse1.gif). I use MATLAB code to calculate the A and b matrices, and the parameter vector, but every time I got
A = -0.0000 B = 0.0000 D =-0.0000 E = 0.5000 F = 0.0000 as result, so C = 1 - A = 1, but this gives $y^2+y=0$ as fitted conic which is a parabola not and ellipse.

First, I get 5 random samples from the edge of the ellipse. Than I put it into the matrix X. I fill X2, so $\left(x_i^2-y_i^2, 2x_iy_i, 2x_i 2y_i, 1\right)$ is the ith row. The b matrix is fille that $y_i$ is the ith row. Then I calculate $p=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$. Is this the correct usage of the method described in the article? If it is, why do I get the equation of a parabola instead?

My MATLAB code:

> I = imread('Ellipse1.gif');
>   I = bwmorph(I, 'thin', Inf);
>   imagesc(I);hold on;
>   [y,x] = find(I);
>   idx = randsample(length(y),5);
>   X = [ x(idx(1)), y(idx(1)); x(idx(2)), y(idx(2)); x(idx(3)), y(idx(3)); x(idx(4)), (idx(4)); x(idx(5)), y(idx(5)) ];
>   X2 = [ X(1,1)^2-X(1,2)^2, 2*X(1,1)*X(1,2), 2*X(1,1), 2*X(1,2), 1;
>         X(2,1)^2-X(2,2)^2, 2*X(2,1)*X(2,2), 2*X(2,1), 2*X(2,2), 1;
>         X(3,1)^2-X(3,2)^2, 2*X(3,1)*X(3,2), 2*X(3,1), 2*X(3,2), 1;
>         X(4,1)^2-X(4,2)^2, 2*X(4,1)*X(4,2), 2*X(4,1), 2*X(4,2), 1;
>         X(5,1)^2-X(5,2)^2, 2*X(5,1)*X(5,2), 2*X(5,1), 2*X(5,2), 1 ];
>   b  = [ X(1,2); X(2,2); X(3,2); X(4,2); X(5,2) ];
>   p = (X2'*X2)\X2'*b

Comment: We don't debug code. You might try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active  but make an effort to give more background.

Comment: I removed the sums-of-squares tag because it was not clear how that was related.  If it is related somehow, please make the connection clearer.